# filtering gzip file using bash

Tags: awk

I have a file with following layout:

```
sample1

//
longitude:32,18,183,918
latitude: 82,8173,183,917
0100
9183
9138
0183
9183
0383
9183
9183
9173

sample2

//
longitude:615,817
latitude: 81,193
81
71
83
81
91
91
81
12
83
```

I want a final gzip file that looks like:

```
sample1

//
longitude:32,18,183,918
latitude: 82,8173,183,917
0100
9183
9138

sample2

//
longitude:615,817
latitude: 81,193
81
71
83
```

So I want only first three digits after the latitude line instead of 9. The rest of file remains the same. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

An alternative using `awk` to gather the 8 lines beginning with `sample[[:digit:]]+` could be written as follows to automatically filter and gzip the file on-the-fly, e.g.

```
awk '$1~/sample[[:digit:]]+$/{n=1} n<9{print;n++} n==9{print"";n++}' file |
gzip -c - > file.gz
```

(**note:** a line continuation isn't necessary after a pipe `'|'`, and the command can be put on a single line -- it was separated into two lines for readability)

For large data files, this method will be highly efficient as filtering is done with a single-pass through the data.

**Example Use/Output**

With your input in the file named `file`, you would filter and gzip by simply select-copying and middle-mouse-pasting the the above command into your xterm with `file` in the current working directory, e.g.

```
$ awk '$1~/sample[[:digit:]]+$/{n=1} n<9{print;n++} n==9{print"";n++}' file |
gzip -c - > file.gz
```

Confirming the contents of `file.gz`

```
$ zcat file.gz
sample1

//
longitude:32,18,183,918
latitude: 82,8173,183,917
0100
9183
9138

sample2

//
longitude:615,817
latitude: 81,193
81
71
83
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `grep` and `sed`:

```
sed 's/--//g' <(grep -A 7 'sample' src.txt) > filtered.txt
```

Contents of src.txt:

```
sample1

//
longitude:32,18,183,918
latitude: 82,8173,183,917
0100
9183
9138
0183
9183
0383
9183
9183
9173

sample2

//
longitude:615,817
latitude: 81,193
81
71
83
81
91
91
81
12
83
```

Contents of filtered.txt after command execution:

```
sample1

//
longitude:32,18,183,918
latitude: 82,8173,183,917
0100
9183
9138

sample2

//
longitude:615,817
latitude: 81,193
81
71
83
```

Comment: Why not `sed 's/--//g' <(grep -A 7 'sample' src.txt) | gzip -c - > src.gz` to compress on the fly? (you should note that the *process substitution* is a bash only feature) Also, we generally require questions to show their attempts before answering (SO isn't a coding or tutorial service -- but questions like this of the "How do I ... ?" sort are somewhat borderline cases) However, you have a good use of `grep` and `sed` if the file format is constant, so it is worthy of the UV.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, thanks for the feedback and the refactor.  Duly noted as to SO as a  coding/tutorial service.